# Should I migrate to MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, migration, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC2 project, my question is: should I migrate to MVC3? Why?

I'd like the opinion of some who already migrated, or at least used MVC3 and MVC2.

Already read http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx

and I already know about the described tool for migrating: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/marcinon/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool)

What I'd really appreciate is your valuable insight.

Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most compelling reason why I switched, was the razor view engine. It's just so beautiful to read and easier on your fingers. It turns spaghetti views, into elegant simple to parse terse code.

Check out the [ASP.Net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) tag on StackOverflow.

Specifically - [Does razor syntax provide a compelling advantage in UI markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019740/does-razor-syntax-provide-a-compelling-advantage-in-ui-markup)

Answer (score 3):

A big plus for me is MvcScaffolding. See [Scaffold your ASP.NET MVC 3 project with the MvcScaffolding package](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/)